# Как реализовать счетчик частоты употребления слова в тексте? (С++)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Дана задача вывести часто встречаемое слово в тексте.

Как в данном коде сделать счётчик частоты появления слова в тексте, и как убрать ограничение на вводимый текст?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void mostRecent(char *, char *); // прототип функции поиска часто встречающегося слова

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");   // установка локалии
    cout << "Введите текст:\n";

    const int buff_size = 1001; // максимальное количество вводимых символов + позиция под '\0'
    char buff_text[buff_size];  // символьный массив, который хранит введённый текст
    char word[30];             // строка, в которй будет храниться искомое слово

    mostRecent(gets(buff_text), word); // вызов функции поиска часто встречающегося слова
    for (int counter = 0; counter < strlen(word); counter++)
        word[counter] = toupper(word[counter]); // преобразование символов слова в верхний регистр
    cout << "Cамое часто встречающееся слово в тексте: " << word << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void mostRecent(char * text, char *word) // функция поиска часто встречающегося слова
{
    int words_counter = 0; // количество слов в тексте
    char *arrayPtr[1000];  //массив указателей на строки, в которых будут храниться слова из текста
    arrayPtr[0] = strtok(text, " "); // нулевому указателю присваеваем первое слово
    // подсчёт количества слов во введённом тексте
    while (arrayPtr[words_counter] != NULL) // пока в тексте есть слова
    {
        words_counter++; // инкремент счётчика слов
        arrayPtr[words_counter] = strtok(NULL, " "); // очередное слово сохраняем в массиве
    }

    bool first_iter = true, // флаг определяющий этап первой итерации
        go = false;
    int max_number1 = 0, // количество слов
        max_number2 = 0, // количество слов
        max_word = 0,    // индекс самого часто встречающегося слова
        flag = 0;        // флаг, подсчёта двух итераций
    int index1, index2;
    for (int counter1 = 0; counter1 < (words_counter - 1); counter1++) // перебор слов, начиная с первого и заканчивая предпоследним
    {
        flag++; // инкремент итераций
        for (int counter2 = counter1 + 1; counter2 < words_counter; counter2++) // перебор слов, начиная со второго и заканчивая предпоследним
        {
            if (strcmp(arrayPtr[counter1], arrayPtr[counter2]) == 0) // сравниваем два слова
            if (first_iter) // если первая итерация (то есть сюда заходим один раз)
            {
                max_number1++; // инкремент переменной, подсчитывающей количество одинаковых слов
                first_iter = false; // меняем условие оператора if
                index1 = counter1;
            }
            else
            {
                max_number2++; // инкремент переменной, подсчитывающей количество одинаковых слов
                index2 = counter1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 2 || go) // если прошли две итерации, или поэлементный проход разрешён
        {
            if (max_number1 >= max_number2) // если количество первого слова больше количества второго слова
            {
                max_word = index1; // присваиваем индекс самого часто повторяющегося слова
            }
            else { max_word = index2; max_number1 = max_number2; } // присваиваем индекс самого часто повторяющегося слова и количество появления второго слова присваиваем переменной max_number1
            flag = 0; // обнуляем счётчик итераций
            go = true; // разрешить поэлементный проход
        }
        max_number2 = 0; // обнуляем накопленное количество появления второго слова
    }

    strcpy(word, arrayPtr[max_word]); // возвращаем результат поиска самого часто встречающегося слова
}
```

Comment: ваш код очень подробно прокомментирован. Думаю, если вы видите С++ не в первый раз в жизни, то легко сможете справиться с задачей сами.

Comment: @dmitriy1995, а попробуйте почитать о [map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) и переписать программу. 

Думаю строк в 20 уложитесь.